# Binomial coefficients prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n+1\choose k+1}=2^{n+1}-1 $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is: Prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n+1\choose k+1}=2^{n+1}-1.$$

It is not clear to me why this $-1$ occurs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because your sum lacks a $\binom{n+1}0$ term.

Comment: Why, for example, the result for : $  \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n+2\choose k+2} 
 $ is not $2^{n+2}-2$, already $2^{n+2}-n-3 $ ?

Comment: That's **another** question; your second sum lacks both a $\binom{n+2}1$ and a $\binom{n+2}0$.

Comment: Amplifying Angina Seng's comment,
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}.$ Therefore,
the question reduces to first evaluating
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}.$

Comment: Thanks, a lot !

Comment: You can find some identical problems on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%7Bn%2B1%5Cchoose%20k%2B1%7D%3D2%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D-1.%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

For a combinatorial proof, count the nonempty subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ in two ways.  The RHS takes all subsets and subtracts $1$ for the empty set.  The LHS conditions on the cardinality $k+1$ of the subset.